# Configure vsftpd to upload multiple hosted websites by multiple users

Tags: nginx, ftp, vsftpd, hosting

I am new to ubuntu world, and I need some help configuring vsftpd for my needs.

I have many sites hosted on nginx. Each site has its own person who is required to upload site contents using FTP (like a hosting company). I must give clients FTP accounts to upload their sites by themselves in the /var/www/ folder. (just like a control panel).

How can I configure vsftpd to do that?
Can I do it without adding a system wide user and giving it to users?
What's the name of the FTP server that is used by hosting companies?

I've searched and seen many guides on the internet, but haven't been able to solve the issue, yet.

Thank you, guys, for your help.